# Problems keeping session on the physical device but not on the emulator. flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to keep the session or login using shared preferences but in the emulator when I do a hot restart or reload it works fine.
The problem arises when I close the application on the physical device or use another app as it does not validate so that the corresponding screen appears if you are logged in.

En dipositivo fisico se queda en la pantalla login.

here is the code

```
 // flutter
    
    class Frm_Login extends State<frm_Login>{
    
    var islogin = null;
    
     Future<void> CheckLoginUusuario() async {
        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
         islogin = prefs.getBool("CheckEstadoLogin");
         
      }
      @override
  void initState() {
    CheckLoginUusuario();
    super.initState();
  }
     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return islogin == true ? MenuPrincipal():
      LoginPage(
      child: new TextButton(
                          onPressed: (){
    
                            if(KeyFormValidaciones.currentState.validate()){
                             
                              validarLoginservices.ValidarLogin(Contrasena.text,Usuario.text , context);
                             
                            }
                          },
                          child: new Text("Login",style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 25,color: Colors.white),),
                        )
    );
    
    }
    
    class ValidarLoginServices {
    
     SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    
    Future ValidateLogin(ContrasenaLogin,CorreoLogin,BuildContext context) async {
    
    if(// if validate password and email is ok ){
    await prefs.setBool("CheckEstadoLogin", true);
 Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>MenuPrincipal()), (route) => false);
    }}}
```

Comment: Where is the navigation code?

Comment: Please share your full updated code ..its really tough to understand the problem

Comment: in the Frm_Login class in the widget build returns 2 screens(Main Menu or Login) depends on whether the islogin variable is true or not.
In the checkLogin method I obtain the value of the shared preferences